# Adding Tap gesture recognizer to only text of UITextfield which is Uneditable

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, uitapgesturerecognizer

I am adding tap gesture recognizer  in a table view like this.

```
# let tapGestureRecognizer = CustomTapGestureRecogniser(target: self, action: #selector(openMethod(tapGestureRecognizer:)))
                        tapGestureRecognizer.data = indexPath.row
                        cell.textField.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
                        cell.textField.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)
```

But the whole textfield is clickable, I want this only on click of text

Comment: What are you trying to do with this tap gesture? There may be a better solution but you need to update your question with a clear explanation of what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Do you want only some text to be selected or do you want to select text when white space is not clicked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can get it with this trick:

```
textField.subviews[1].subviews.first?.subviews[3]
```

you can see the view in "**debug view hierarchy**"(3D view) when your UIViewController is rendered:

[image]

and via right click on the view and choose the "**Reveal in debug navigator**" you can see the view hierarchy:

[image]

an see the hierarchy of the views:

[image]

and after that you can get it

note that, in the update of iOS SDK it may change, you should check it if exist:

```
if textField.subviews.count > 1,  
textField.subviews[1].subviews.count > 0, 
textField.subviews[1].subviews.first?.subviews.count > 3 {
   textField.subviews[1].subviews.first?.subviews[3]
}
```

you can see the hierarchy of the views with PO(print object command) like as:

[image]

[image]

Comment: @prassana-kudle did you check?

Answer (score 0):

You could set your text as an attributed string with a link attribute.